# Replace Information.RGB in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, colors

```
public static int DarkenColor1(int oleColor, float sngRatio)
{
    int R= oleColor & 255;
    int G= (int)(((long)oleColor & 65280L) / 256L);
    int B= (oleColor & 16711680) / 65536;               
    return Information.RGB((int)(R / sngRatio), (int)(G / sngRatio), (int)(B / sngRatio));            
}
```

How to replace `Information.RGB`, which is VB.NET, in pure C# code? I am not prefer `using Microsoft.VisualBasic`.

Comment: Color.FromArgb() ?

Comment: Color.FromArgb returns Color, not int.

Comment: Well then `Color.FromArgb(r,g,b).ToArgb();`

Comment: It is not a RGB OLEColor.  I tested.

Comment: use ColorTranslator.ToOle. I tested, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using ColorTranslator.ToOle to translates a specified C# Color structure to an OLE color.

```
public static int DarkenColor1(int oleColor, float sngRatio)
{
    int R= oleColor & 255;
    int G= (int)(((long)oleColor & 65280L) / 256L);
    int B= (oleColor & 16711680) / 65536;               
    //return Information.RGB((int)(R / sngRatio), (int)(G / sngRatio), (int)(B / sngRatio)); 
    return ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.FromArgb((int)(R / sngRatio), (int)(G / sngRatio), (int)(B / sngRatio));            
}
```